# Content type with 3 paragraphs fields: How can I output to different parts of page.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 9, paragraphs

I have a content type called (*My Page*) with 3 paragraph types, for a slider to display images, for text to display text, and for sidebar content. (The sidebar is a `<div>`, not a Drupal region/block).

Using the *page.html.twig* template, I am able to output the content to `{{ page.content }}`. However, it dumps all the content of all 3 paragraph types in one place.
I'd like to be able to separate the content as in this screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

Paragraph type 1 should be rendered in `<header>`, paragraph type 2 in `<main>`, and paragraph type 3 in `<div id="sidebar">`.

The *page.html.twig* template is the following. (I simplified the section responsible for outputting the paragraph type content.)

{% block content %}

*****I'd like to paragraph type 1 to output here****
     
         {{ page.content }}  *****I'd like to paragraph type 2 to output here****
     
    
  *****I'd like to paragraph type 3 to output here**** 
 {% endblock %}
```

I use the Barrio subtheme.

If I can just figure out how to separate the content across the 3 `<div>`, that would be great.

Is there a conditional logic I could use?

```
if paragraph type 1 machine name  = X 
{{ page.content}}
if paragraph type 2 machine name = Y
{{ page.content}}
if paragraph type 3 machine name = Z
{{ page.content}}
```

This has me stumped as a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The`page.html.twig` isn't the twig which prints the content of a node, but rather one which prints the markup of the entire page.

To avoid confusion, I'm taking the `article` node bundle as example.
If you want to customize its content you should override`node--article--full.html.twig` or `node--article.html.twig` for all the displays of the bundle.

Inside you can use

```
 {% block content %}
  <header> {{content.field_paragraph_1}}</header> {# the field name of the pragraph #}
     <main>
         {{ content | without('field_paragraph_1, field_paragraph_1) }}
     </main>
    
  <div id="sidebar">{{content.field_paragraph_3}}</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

You should always print all the `content` renderable array inside a `node` twig, use the `without` filter to avoid to print twice the fields you have manually inserted in other lines of the template.

Comment: I think you're mixing a bit the context of different templates. E.g. the `node` templates won't have the `page` renderable array because those are different template. The `node` template contains usually only variables related to the node itself. And *usually* is better to keep the layout separate, so not to print the "page" variables, namely the regions, inside the node template. 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal here's a bit of more documentation, including the available filters, like `without`. Twig Tweak is anyway a must-have module.